# Disable Automatic Updates with PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell

I would like to know how to disable Automatic Updates with PowerShell on a windows machine.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a couple functions to set and get Windows Update configurations

```
$SCRIPT:AutoUpdateNotificationLevels= @{   

0="Not configured"; 
1="Disabled"; 
2="Notify before download";
3="Notify before installation"; 
4="Scheduled installation"

}

$SCRIPT:AutoUpdateDays=@{
0="Every Day"; 
1="Every Sunday"; 
2="Every Monday"; 
3="Every Tuesday"; 
4="Every Wednesday";
5="Every Thursday"; 
6="Every Friday"; 
7="Every Saturday"
}


Function Get-WindowsUpdateConfig
{
    $AUSettings = (New-Object -com "Microsoft.Update.AutoUpdate").Settings
    $AUObj = New-Object -TypeName System.Object

    Add-Member -inputObject $AuObj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "NotificationLevel"  `
               -Value $AutoUpdateNotificationLevels[$AUSettings.NotificationLevel]

    Add-Member -inputObject $AuObj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "UpdateDays" `
               -Value $AutoUpdateDays[$AUSettings.ScheduledInstallationDay]

    Add-Member -inputObject $AuObj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "UpdateHour"   `
               -Value $AUSettings.ScheduledInstallationTime 

    Add-Member -inputObject $AuObj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Recommended updates" `
               -Value $(IF ($AUSettings.IncludeRecommendedUpdates) {"Included"}  else {"Excluded"})
    $AuObj
 } 

Function Set-WindowsUpdateConfig
{
Param (

[Parameter()]
[ValidateRange(0,4)]
[int]
$NotificationLevel , 

[Parameter()]
[ValidateRange(0,7)]
[int]
$Day, 

[Parameter()]
[ValidateRange(0,24)]
[int]
$hour, 

[Parameter()]
[bool]
$IncludeRecommended
)

 $AUSettings = (New-Object -com "Microsoft.Update.AutoUpdate").Settings
 if ($NotificationLevel)  {$AUSettings.NotificationLevel        =$NotificationLevel}
 if ($Day)                {$AUSettings.ScheduledInstallationDay =$Day}
 if ($hour)               {$AUSettings.ScheduledInstallationTime=$hour}
 if ($IncludeRecommended) {$AUSettings.IncludeRecommendedUpdates=$IncludeRecommended}
 $AUSettings.Save()
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andy! Actually I only needed to modify an attribute of the object. This solution is a little bit of an overkill for what I needed but it helped me a lot to understand how Powershell works. I assume it was the goal :)

Comment: From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wuapi/nf-wuapi-iautomaticupdatessettings-get_scheduledinstallationday): Starting with Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012, **ScheduledInstallationDay is not supported** and will return unreliable values. If you try to modify ScheduledInstallationDay, the operation will appear to succeed but will have no effect.

Comment: Another point from [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wuapi/nf-wuapi-iautomaticupdatessettings-get_scheduledinstallationtime): Starting with Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012, **ScheduledInstallationTime is not supported** and will return unreliable values. If you try to modify ScheduledInstallationTime, the operation will appear to succeed but will have no effect.

Comment: @Andy How do I enable it back? I want to test in my pc first. But need a revert function or vice versa. I want to run a fully disable at another unattended pc/running in kiosk. Currently, the windows notification is appear on top of the application.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a link and how to set the registry settings

```
# http://support.microsoft.com/kb/328010

New-Item HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows -Name WindowsUpdate
New-Item HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate -Name AU
New-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU -Name NoAutoUpdate -Value 1
```

Comment: Thanks Doug! It works fine but the UI isn't updated. More RegKeys have to be edited to complete the process (I assume that maybe that's not true)

Answer (score 0):

you can use **CMD** command:

```
 sc stop wuauserv
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @aschipfl: Not sure what you're talking about exactly, but lack of explanation is not a valid reason for deleting here, in general. And stopping the WU service undeniably *does* stop updates.

Comment: The question is tagged [tag:powershell], but your answer is related to [tag:cmd]...